# Un-comment a tag in web.config

Tags: xml, powershell, web-config, powershell-2.0

How can I remove the comments from this tag in my web.config?

```
<assemblies>
<!--<add assembly="Telerik.Reporting, Version=4.2.10.1221, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=A9D7983DFCC261BE" />-->
</assemblies>
```

I need a code somewhere across these lines

```
$webConfig = '.\web.config'
[xml]$web =  (Get-Content $webConfig)
'replace the code goes here'
$web.Save($webConfig)
```

Comment: Remove the leading `<!--` and trailing `-->`.

Comment: Is this a trick question? remove the `<!--` and `-->` from the start and end of the tag. Or do you want to do it using PowerShell?

Comment: I think it's obvious the OP wants to use PowerShell, but didn't specifically ask for a PowerShell solution. Unfortunately the question lacks context, and there could very well be a much better solution.

Comment: I need a PowerShell script something across these lines

$webConfig = '.\web.config'
[xml]$web =  (Get-Content $webConfig)
replace the code goes here
$web.Save($webConfig)

Comment: @Naeem, this comment should be in the text of the question. Comments can be deleted, and SO is not a threaded forum, but rather a Q&A site. [Edit] your question so it contains what you want to do, what you tried, and what results you got.

Comment: Question has been edited

Comment: @DanWilson  any ideas

Comment: Yes, but I'm curious: why do you need to uncomment an assembly element? Any solution likely depends on the context and your constraints. Paweł Dyl's answer works, but does it fully meet your needs?

Answer (score 0):

Since there are no constraints, use following:

```
$xml -replace
  '<!--<add assembly="Telerik.Reporting, Version=4.2.10.1221, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=A9D7983DFCC261BE" />-->',
  '<add assembly="Telerik.Reporting, Version=4.2.10.1221, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=A9D7983DFCC261BE" />'
```